# How to Delete Item from Object in NodeJS/Mongo Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm querying for a user object and performing a series of updates on the items within compared to incoming postdata (jsObject). I'm wondering how to completely remove an item from the object...specifically a Date object (user[0].birthDate)...before I make a save of the updated user object.

```
orm.User.find({ appId: appId, facebookUsername:usersFBUsername}).exec(function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error in User Query: ' + error);
        }
        else if(Object.keys(user).length > 0) {

            if(jsObject.name != null)
                user[0].name = jsObject.name;

            if(jsObject.email != null)
                user[0].emailAddress = jsObject.email;

            if(jsObject.birthDate != null && jsObject.birthDate.length > 0) {
                user[0].birthDate = jsObject.birthDate;
            }
            else {
                console.log('delete it');
                //orm.User.update({_id:user._id}, {$pull:{birthDate:1}});
                //delete user[0].birthDate;
            }               
        }

        user[0].save(function (error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    console.log('An error has occurred while saving user:' + error);
                    response.end(results.getResultsJSON(results.ERROR, error));
                }
                else {
                    console.log('    [User Successfully Updated]');
                    response.end('{ "success": ' + JSON.stringify(user[0]) + ' }');
                }
            });
       });
```

You can see in the commented code some attempts I've made which have not been successful. I even gave this a try after the save completed, which also did not work:

```
orm.User.update({appId: appId, facebookUsername:usersFBUsername},{$pull:{birthDate:deleteBirthDate}})
                .exec(function(error){
                    if(error) {
                        console.log('oh well: ' + error);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('maybe maybe');
                    }
                });
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Chris

Comment: delete(field.attribute) will remove attribute field and its value

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: This unfortunately does not work (possibly because I'm using Mongoose?).

Comment: I had thought you were getting back the full object and wanted to delete the field from the json document. if you are trying to unset it when doing the update the answer below is correct.

Comment: No problem. I wasn't saying you were wrong, just that this is not applicable for the outcome I need. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pull` is for removing values from arrays, but you can use `$unset`:

```
orm.User.update(
  {_id     : user._id},
  { $unset : { birthDate : 1 }},
  function(err, numAffected) { 
    ...
  }
);
```

For reference:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/